# change viewcontrolller background color on click on button

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the current view controller background color when a user clicks on one of our radio station buttons.

Each station has a different color, but does not require a new view to open, as all it does it change the music that is playing and fetches a different now playing url. All other functions are the same.

What is the UIkit way to change `view.backgroundColor`

As I have tried the following

```
view.backgroundColor = .red
```

with no success.

```
@objc func play1life(sender:UIButton!){
        currentstation = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8015/stream?uuid=\(uuid ?? "")"
        MusicPlayer.shared.startBackgroundMusic(url: "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8015/stream?uuid=\(uuid ?? "")")
       npinfo = "https://api.drn1.com.au/station/1lifeRadio/playing"
        nowplaying()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
```

Comment: there is some other issue you are facing ....

Comment: I think, This view is covered by other view. So please change color of most upper view. so that color is shown.